# Recover Intel Matrix Raid Configuration

Tags: raid

I had 2 HDDs in Intel Matrix Raid configuration on a motherboard with intel ICH9R. I had some RAID 0 partitions and one RAID 1 partition.

Somehow when replacing my videocard I partially unpulugged the power connector from one of the HDD. I booted and only one disk was showing. So I turned off the PC and correctly plugged the power connector and how both HDDs are showing as "**Non-Raid Disk**"

Is there a way to restore the raid configuration from before ?

In fact I don't really remember how my partitions where configured, I had 2x100Gb + 1x296Gb in RAID 0 and one 50Gb in RAID 1 (using 2x320Gb HDDs) but I'm not sure how many volumes and how the partitions where allocated on the volumes. Is there a tool to find that ?

Answer (score 3):

There is a program called [Zero Assumption Recovery](http://www.z-a-recovery.com/) that will scan all your disks and find matching RAID pairs, and will recover your data from them. So if you have enough disk space on another machine, you should be able to get your Data back - even if the metadata is gone.

I've used it more than once and it's been brilliant. It takes a very long time to scan for the RAID volumes (try 12+ hours) but once it's found them it's worth it.

Answer (score 2):

The hard drives store the RAID information on them themselves.  You may want to ensure that you have them backed up before you try adding them to the raid volume again.  DO NOT, i repeat, DO NOT hook them up to another computer and run any kind of chkdsk or scandisk utility, you'll more than likely break the crap out of the RAID volume.

More than likely, your RAID 0 volume is no longer.  Once you break a RAID 0, you won't be able to get any data off it without using special tools, or a data recovery center.

The RAID 1 volumes are a different story, and you should be able to promote the drives back to RAID 1 without causing any problems.  With the RAID 1 volume, you can mark the drives as RAID once more.  Check your BIOS settings to ensure everything is set up properly.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know it was even possible within the Intel RAID to setup more than one type of RAID volume on the same disk. Are you still able to boot?

Anyway, if it is RAID0, you may have a more serious issue. If you were using RAID 1, then mark the disk as available in the Intel Matrix, and it should rebuild on its own.